# If it doesn't fit the pattern in the list, replace/fix it

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I have a list that occasionally has a string that needs to be replaced when not matching the repeating sequence. I think SED would be best for this task, but I'm open to others.

- If ^n doesn't begin with Chapter_, replace with +5 from above Chapter_
- The misplaced string varies in length and in composition of characters.
- Because sometimes the +5 pattern shifts, I'd like to print a separate file of the replacements for manual inspection.

## Example 1:

#### Input.txt

```
CHAPTERS    START_TIME  END_TIME    DURATION    OTHER_COMMENTS  
Chapter_1   0:00 ..............
Chapter_6
999_8
Chapter_58
Chapter_63
as;li9c
Chapter_121
```

#### Output.txt

```
CHAPTERS    START_TIME  END_TIME    DURATION    OTHER_COMMENTS  
Chapter_1   0:00 ..............
Chapter_6
Chapter_11
Chapter_58
Chapter_63
Chapter_68
Chapter_121
```

#### Replaced.txt

```
999_8   Chapter_11
as;li9c Chapter_68
```

## Example 2:

#### Infile2.txt

```
CHAPTERS    START_TIME  END_TIME    DURATION    OTHER_COMMENTS  
Chapter_00001   0:00    1:16    1:16
Chapter_00006   5:15    6:49    1:34
999_8   9:17    11:17   2:00
Chapter_00058   19:51   20:52   1:01
Chapter_00063   23:01   23:57   0:56
as;li9c 27:42   29:45   2:03
Chapter_00121   64:33   66:33   2:00
```

#### Outfile2.txt

```
CHAPTERS    START_TIME  END_TIME    DURATION    OTHER_COMMENTS  
Chapter_00001   0:00    1:16    1:16
Chapter_00006   5:15    6:49    1:34
Chapter_00011   9:17    11:17   2:00
Chapter_00058   19:51   20:52   1:01
Chapter_00063   23:01   23:57   0:56
Chapter_00068   27:42   29:45   2:03
Chapter_00121   64:33   66:33   2:00
```

#### Replaced2.txt

```
999_8   Chapter_00011
as;li9c Chapter_00068
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` has no arithmetic facilities (although it's not impossible to do). `awk` is better for this task. The following assumes tab-delimiters and a header line. It also retains leading `0`'s in the chapter numbers.

```
awk '
  BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }
  NR == 1 { print; next }
  $1 ~ /^Chapter_/ { n = substr($1, 9); print; next }
  {
    repl = sprintf("Chapter_%0*d", length(n), (n + 5))
    print $1, repl >"replaced.txt"
    print repl, substr($0, index($0, "\t") + 1)
  }
' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by column spacing. I tried making the tab-delimited file in SublimeText, then formatted to post here. Is it not passed to SO correctly?

Comment: @BlacquenedRed You've elided the data so I wasn't really sure how it was laid out. I'll add a second version above that retains tab-delimiters.

Comment: For AWK: substr(string, start, length)... so are you using n to capture the Chapter ## regardless of the number of digits? (e.g., n=1 or n=63) In other words, without specifying the 3rd position 'length' the substr can be any length?

Comment: @BlacquenedRed Yes, exactly. It's handy. If the third argument wasn't optional you'd have to calculate a value based on `length($1)`.

Comment: In another file with the same issue, I have a preceding '00' which is not carried over from the math to the replacement. Is there a simpler way than calculating the length($1) to fill in the preceding 00s?

Comment: The repl with stringf looks right but when I swap that line out it still doesn't retain the leading zeroes and discards the remaining info in the row

Comment: @BlacquenedRed I don't understand how that could happen. Check that you replaced the right line and didn't change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
f=open("input.txt",'r')
z=[]
for part in f:
  if len(z)!=0:
    pattern=re.compile(r"^Chapter_(\d+).*$")
    try:
      k=pattern.match(part).groups()[0]
      z.append(part)
    except:
      rep=int(k)+5
      z.append("Chapter_"+str(rep)+"\n")
  else:
    z.append(part)
f.close()
f=open("output.txt",'w')
for line in z:
  f.write(line)
f.close()
```

This is in python.The problem type was better suited for it.